# nginx map $upstream_addr is not working, always using default

Tags: nginx

I have the following example of a upstream with just 1 server for simplicity:

```
upstream EarthML_IdentityService {
    server localhost:25303 ;
}
map $upstream_addr $EarthML_IdentityServiceuniquepath {
    default "7ab713ad-9ca5-4b08-8d32-84ec2e69370a/131365180085121149";
    127.0.0.1:25303 "7ab713ad-9ca5-4b08-8d32-84ec2e69370a/131365180085121149";
}
```

and location proxy

```
location ~* ^/(subscriptions/.*/)?(resourcegroups/.*/)?providers/(EarthML.Identity) {
        rewrite ^ /$EarthML_IdentityServiceuniquepath$uri break;
        proxy_pass http://earthml_identityservice;
        server_name_in_redirect on;
        port_in_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host                     $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server     $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path       $request_uri;
        proxy_connect_timeout                   3s;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-PathBase   /;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        add_header  X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;
    }
```

but if i remove the `default` entry of the map, then it stop working. I added `add_header  X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;` to the headers to see that  `X-Upstream` is indeed being set to `127.0.0.1:25303`

Comment: `rewrite` executes before `proxy_pass`, so nginx has not determined what the `$upstream_addr` would be.

Comment: Actually, you want something weird. What's the problem you try to solve?

Comment: My problem was that the services beering proxies was backed by 3 nodes, but on each node the services paths was prefixed with different unique prefixes. This is service fabric on azure that can be set up like this, because then when the nameservice resolves the services in case of application upgrades, it has a chance to discard bad requests that ended up at the wrong service. I my my own implementation which skipped these unique prefixes and used a custom header to do the same verification and therefore I could simplifiy the nginx stuff.  I agree, above is weird.

Answer (score 0):

To provide abit of context. I have a microservice framework setup in Microsoft ServiceFabric.

I am using nginx infront of all  services for doing public mapping of routes to correct services.

In the latest version a new functionality was added `UseServiceFabricIntegration` which allowed service fabric when setting up service listeneres and services to prefix all service urls with a [suffix](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-aspnetcore/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore/AspNetCoreCommunicationListener.cs#L52)

In a 3 node setup, this means that the service `A` will be prefixed with 3 different suffixes, one for each node. This integration also [sets up](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-aspnetcore/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore/ServiceFabricMiddleware.cs) a check that when communicating with this service that the suffix should match, otherwise return 410 GONE.

I was trying to create a upstream configuration in nginx that could reroute a request to one of the other two nodes incase the primary node failed to respond. (A node here is that I have the nginx loadbalancer running on each node and until now I have used a configuration without upstream such all requests for nginx on node 1 also would map to servics on node 1.)

I wanted to change this behavior to make ready for next version where I want to be able to have nginx running on seperate nodes and map to services on different nodes and also as described above to reroute in case of service errors on the same node.

The main problem is that there was no way to solve this in nginx with upstream servers due to those different suffixes as the original question was asked.

## Solution

I instead dropped this service fabric integration implementation that was build in for aspnet core and rolled my own.

in nginx configuration genration I added:

```
sb.AppendLine($"{tabs}proxy_set_header X-ServiceFabric-Key    {uniquekey};");
```

where `uniquekey` was created from the service name and service manifest version `$"\"{ServiceName.AbsoluteUri.Substring("fabric:/".Length)}/{ServiceVersion}\""`

I added my own startupfilter to check that this key was added:

```
if(context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-ServiceFabric-Key", out StringValues serviceFabricKey))
{
    if (!serviceFabricKey.FirstOrDefault().Equals(this.serviceFabricKey))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status410Gone;
        return;
    }
}
```

since I also uses http communication for some internal communication between services I added a quick example to do a get request:

```
public class HttpCommunicationServicePartitionClient : ServicePartitionClient<HttpCommunicationClient>
{
    private readonly FabricClient fabricClient;
    private readonly Uri application;
    public HttpCommunicationServicePartitionClient(
        FabricClient fabricClient, Uri application, Uri serviceUri, ServicePartitionKey partitionKey = null, TargetReplicaSelector targetReplicaSelector = TargetReplicaSelector.Default, string listenerName = null, OperationRetrySettings retrySettings = null)
        : base(new HttpCommunicationClientFactory(new ServicePartitionResolver(() => fabricClient)), serviceUri, partitionKey, targetReplicaSelector, listenerName, retrySettings)
    {

        this.fabricClient = fabricClient;
        this.application = application;

    }

    public string BearerToken { get; set; }


    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string pathAndQuery)
    {
        return InvokeWithRetryAsync(async (client) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BearerToken))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", BearerToken);
            }

            var services = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetServiceListAsync(application, ServiceUri).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var service = services.FirstOrDefault();
            var key = $"{ServiceUri.AbsoluteUri.Substring("fabric:/".Length)}/{service.ServiceManifestVersion}";

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ServiceFabric-Key", key);


            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(client.BaseAddress, pathAndQuery));
            return response;
        });
    }



}
```